# Modal does not close when submitting / Embed is sent as intended

Tags: javascript, discord.js

can someone point me in the right direction?
When I use this command the embed is sent as intended to the server and channel - the modal will show anyway "Something went wrong. Try again". I don't get any error in console but neither the success message nor the failure message is being send. The modal does not close as mentioned.

````js
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    EmbedBuilder,
    ModalBuilder,
    TextInputBuilder,
    TextInputStyle,
    ActionRowBuilder,
    ChatInputCommandInteraction,
} = require("discord.js");

    module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("bugreport")
    .setDescription("Report a bug in the bot")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
        option
          .setName("severity")
          .setDescription("Select the severity level of the bug")
          .addChoices(
            { name: "Low", value: "low" },
            { name: "Medium", value: "medium" },
            { name: "High", value: "high" }
          )
          .setRequired(true)
      ),

      /**
       *
       * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction
       */
      async execute(interaction) {
        const severity = interaction.options.getString("severity");
        const reportModal = new ModalBuilder()
          .setCustomId("bugmodal")
          .setTitle("Report a bug");

        const titleInput = new TextInputBuilder()
          .setCustomId("bugtitle")
          .setLabel("Title")
          .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
          .setPlaceholder("Cool Title!")
          .setMaxLength(256)
          .setRequired(false);

        const descriptionInput = new TextInputBuilder()
          .setCustomId("bugdescription")
          .setLabel("Description")
          .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
          .setRequired(false);

        const titleactionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(titleInput);
        const descriptionactionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
          descriptionInput
        );

        reportModal.addComponents(titleactionRow, descriptionactionRow);

        try {
          await interaction.showModal(reportModal);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return interaction.reply({
            content: "Something went wrong",
            ephemeral: true,
          });
        }

        try {
            const response = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({ time: 300000 });
          const title = response.fields.getTextInputValue("bugtitle");
            const description = response.fields.getTextInputValue("bugdescription");

          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("Red")
            .setTitle(`${severity.toUpperCase()} Priority Bug Report`)
            .addFields(
              { name: "Title", value: title },
              { name: "Description", value: description },
              { name: "Reported By:", value: interaction.user.tag },
              { name: "Reported from:", value: interaction.guild.name }
            )
            .setTimestamp();
    
          const guildId = "1090231817795272725";
          const channelId = "1090231818596397088";

          const guild = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch(guildId);
          const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);

          await channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

          if (!interaction.replied && !interaction.deferred) {
            console.log("sending success message");
            return interaction.reply({
              content: "Bug report sent successfully!",
              ephemeral: true,
            });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
          if (!interaction.replied && !interaction.deferred) {
            return interaction.reply({
              content: "Something went wrong",
              ephemeral: true,
            });
          }
        }
      },
    };```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with following changes:

```
   try {
    await channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    await interaction.followUp({ content: "Bug report sent succesfully to support server!", ephemeral: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.followUp({
      content: "Failed to send bug report",
      ephemeral: true,
    });
```